# How do I create a solid ellipse and fill it with a specific color in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a beginner to three.js. Here's my code where I have created a linear ellipse. All I want is a solid ellipse with a solid color.
 
  I also wanted to know how can I drag the solid ellipse once created across the screen.

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
0,  0,            // ax, aY
2, 16,           // xRadius, yRadius
0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
false,            // aClockwise
0                 // aRotation
);

//ellipse
var path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 50 ) );
var geometry = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color : 0x59d1c1} );
var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(ellipse);
```

Comment: there are shapes here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `THREE.Shape` and `THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry` classes. Here is an example:

```
var path = new THREE.Shape();
path.absellipse(0,0,2,16,0, Math.PI*2, false,0);
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( path );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x59d1c1} );
var ellipse = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(ellipse);
```